# How to declare a tuple in Swift with a runtime function for one of the members

Tags: swift, tuples, getter, func

Is it possible in Swift, and how, to make a member of a tuple be a function rather than a data value, similar to JavaScript? As in:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

example (pseudo code):

`(title: func get {
  return the_title_i_want_to_choos_at_runtime ()
})`

Answer (score 0):

Sure, since functions are first-class objects in Swift.

```
import Foundation

typealias LazyEvalTuple = ( timeSince1970: (Void -> NSTimeInterval), now: (Void -> String) )

let lazyTup = LazyEvalTuple ( { return NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 }, { return "\(NSDate())" } )

print(lazyTup.timeSince1970())
print(lazyTup.now())

// Do it again and observe different results, proving dynamic evaluation
print(lazyTup.timeSince1970())
print(lazyTup.now())

print(lazyTup.1)
print(lazyTup.0)
```

Output:

```
1473288631.22304
2016-09-07 22:50:31 +0000
1473288631.22619
2016-09-07 22:50:31 +0000
(Function)
(Function)
```